# Convert values outside a range to the range's bounds

Tags: r, vector

If I have a series of values

```r
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
```

and a given range (a, b), e.g.

```r
a <- -1; b <- 2
```

How could I move those values less than `a` to `a` and those greater than `b` to `b`?

The following basic method works but I'm searching a function or a one-liner command.

```r
x[x < a] <- a
x[x > b] <- b
```

Comment: not sure why having 2 lines is a big deal, but e.g. `scales::squish` will do this. Or you can write something like `ifelse(x < a, a, ifelse(x > b, b, x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need a single line, use `pmin/pmax`

```
out <- pmin(pmax(x, a), b)
```

-checking

```
x[x < a] <- a
x[x > b] <- b
identical(out, x)
[1] TRUE
```